# Entity Framework LINQ Include - Child Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am loading the child entity `UserStarted` from my **TransactionDetails**

```
var result = (from A in context.Transactions.Include(_ => _.TransactionDetails.Select(us => us.UserStarted))
              select A).SingleOrDefault();
```

Now I want to load another entity, but I don't know how. The entity is similar to `UserStarted`, it's the `UserEnded` also from **TransactionDetails**

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain multiple include predicates together:

```
var result = context.Transactions
  .Include(transaction => transaction.TransactionDetails.Select(us => us.UserStarted))
  .Include(transaction => transaction.TransactionDetails.Select(us => us.UserEnded))
  .SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
 var result = (from A in context.Transactions.Include(_ => _.TransactionDetails.Select(us => new { UserStarted  = us.UserStarted, UserEnded = us.UserEnded }))
select A).SingleOrDefault();
```